# Java Generics & Inheritance: am I trying to be too clever?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I may be an idiot, but I haven't been able to figure this one out. I'm trying to setup some classes for a simple CRUD framework with a DB.

I start with an **`Entity`** interface and a **`Users implements Entity`** class.

Then as "dao" classes I have an interface

```
GenericTableModel<T extends Entity>
```

with the usual functions, then an abstract class

```
AbstractTableModel<T extends Entity> implements GenericTableModel<T>
```

that implements the common functions such as `List<T> listAll()`, and finally a

```
UsersTable extends AbstractTableModel<Users> implements GenericTableModel<Users>
```

These are the constructors for

```
AbstractTableModel( Class<T> classType ){ this.type = classType; } and
UsersTable() { super( Users.class ); }
```

So the following code works as expected: the `listAll()` method in `AsbtractTableModel` is invoked, *magic* happens, and I get a list of `Users` objects.

```
UsersTable ut = new UsersTable();
List<Users> usrLst = ut.listAll();
```

However when I add the following classes things change:

```
public abstract class AbstractCrud<T extends GenericTableModel> {
    private T table;

    public AbstractCrud( T t ){ this.table = t }

    public List<? extends Entity> getList(){
        return this.table.listAll()
    }
```

and

```
public class UserSimpleCrud extends AbstractCrud {
    public UserSimpleCrud()
    {
        super( new UsersTable() );
    }
```

`super.getList()` does not return a list of `Users`, just a `List` of objects. In order to get a list of `Users` I need the following method in `UserSimpleCrud`

```
    @Override
    public List<Users> getList(){
        return super.getList();
    }
```

that will automatically cast the list of objects to one of `Users`.

Sooo.... what am I missing here? Other than a few grey cells, obviously! ;-)

Why is the `listAll()` method in `AsbtractTableModel` able to cast the list to `Users` but the the `getList()` in `AbstractCrud` is not able to?

Comment: Shouldn't that be public class `UserSimpleCrud extends AbstractCrud<UsersTable>`otherwise T is not defined in your abstract class.

Comment: What's the difference between a *Model and a *Crud here?

Comment: I revise my comment. Ok, I think you need two generics. One for the table and one for the entity. Otherwise you will never receive an entity of a specific type. `public List<E> getList()` will return the entities of your T, and your class shoud be `<T extends GenericTable<E extends Entity>>`. I think this should get you closer to what you want.

Comment: BheshGurung :

    The *Model classes represent a table in the database.
    The *Crud classes will be beans (I'm working with JSF/PrimeFaces).

Comment: @thst : I tried what you suggest, however `<T extends GenericTable<E extends Entity>>' is marked as an error in NetBeans (7.3.1). If I change it to `<T extends GenericTable<Entity>>` then it's OK, but I'm not sure how the `UserSimpleCrud` class should change...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this

```
public abstract class AbstractCrud<T extends Entity> {
    private GenericTableModel<T> table;

    public AbstractCrud( GenericTableModel<T> table ){ this.table = table }

    public List<T> getList(){
        return this.table.listAll()
    }



public class UserSimpleCrud extends AbstractCrud<User> {
    public UserSimpleCrud(){
        super( new UsersTable() );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing my own rather than using, say, Spring Data (which has served me well for these types of situations), I would do something like:

```
public abstract class AbstractCrud<T extends GenericTableModel, E extends Entity> {
    private T table;

    public AbstractCrud( T t ){ this.table = t }

    public List<E> getList(){
        return this.table.listAll()
    }
}
```

From there,

```
public class UserSimpleCrud extends AbstractCrud<GenericTableModel<User>, User> {
    public UserSimpleCrud()
    {
        super( new UsersTable() );
    }
}
```

should get you what you are looking for.  This is off the top of my head, but I think it will work for you.

Comment: You're using a raw type of GenericTableModel at `AbstractCrud<T extends GenericTableModel, E extends Entity>`

Comment: That's what happens when I answer off the top of my head... Thanks, Puce.